# Share private key in android development

Tags: android, eclipse, key, share, private

I am developing an android app, on two machines, one at work and other at home.
But when I compile and run on first machine, then goto second machine and change and compile and run Eclipse errors that signatures are different and I first should uninstall previously installed app.

Is there any way to share this private key between machines?

Thank you.

Comment: Get Dropbox.  Put the private key there.  Configure Eclipse to use the shared one. Preferences -> Android -> Build -> Custom keystore

Comment: Why Dropbox, use git or cvs at least for distributed development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Windows->Preferences->Android->Build* contains the setting to specify the keystore file. Be sure this file is the same on all machines you use to develop the same applications, maybe simply place into content repository along the project files. The key is randomly generated on every installation but the username, password Android SDK uses are the same. This keystore anyway cannot (and should not be) used in production.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just take the keystore from one machine, and overwrite the one in the other. The debug keystores have the same name and password across all installs, so you should be able to replace them easily.

On UNIX systems, the keystore is at `~/.android/debug.keystore`